# Server 2008 Drive mapping scripts vs GPO

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get familiar with our work server and I've just noticed that the IT support crowd have mapped network drives with scripts;

GPO Editor > User config > Policies > Windows settings > Scripts > Logon

rather than just adding the drive straight in by the policy from;

GPO Editor > User config > Preferences > Windows settings > Drive maps

Is there some advantage to using scripts? Any tutorials on drive mapping I've seen have used the second method.

Comment: One is a policy. One is a preference. Please go explore the differences.